# Hashing the content of a method in Python

Tags: python, hash

I am looking for a robust way to hash/serialize the content of a method in Python.

Use-case: We are doing some file caching the result of a transformation function, and it would be great if it was possible to automatically refresh if transformation function has changed:

```py
cached_file = get_cached_filename(
    data_version=data.version,
    transform_version=1,  # increment this when making updates
)

# Return the cached file if present
if cached_file.exists() and not overwrite:
    logger.debug("Reading dataset from local cache")
    return joblib.load(cached_file)
    
logger.debug("Downloading dataset and storing to local cache")

# Do the expensive data download and transform
df = download_and_apply_transforms(data)

# Store dataframe to local data cache
joblib.dump(df, cached_file)

return df
```

I am looking for something that could potentially replace my hardcoding of a version in `transform_version=1`, but rather read a hash from the method itself.

I tried using the built-in hash method of a callable. I.e. `download_and_apply_transforms.__hash__()`, but it seems to update on each re-run, so it likely bases itself on memory location somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Not sure if it is the best approach, but you can get the function source code using `inspect` module, like this:

```
inspect.getsource(foo)
```

That will return the source as a string, so you can then get the hash to get a cache key by running some hashing function.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that one. It'll do the job. The only downside I can think of is that we can have changes to the source that does not affect runtime (e.g. comments, whitespaces, etc.), but that'll be difficult to solve I suppose, and it isn't really a big deal for us.

Comment: Actually, the `hash(..)` seems to provide new results on re-runs. So using an `md5` encoder on the source code as string itself works better.

Comment: good point, I'll update the answer